# MYSQL - returning only max result from an ID

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line

I wasn't quite sure how to title it as its quite a strange question. I'm building a slightly advanced query and it all it works fine except it returns all information under that ID

Below is my code:

```
select surname, salary_per_year, position _held, grade, name 
from person inner join career_history on person.person_id = career_history.person_id
join grade on grade.person_id = career_history.person_id
join school on grade.school_id = school.school_id
where salary_per_year > 20000 and grade >65;
```

This creates this table.

```
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------+---------------------------+
| surname  | salary_per_year | position_held      | grade | name                      |
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------+---------------------------+
| webster  |           32000 | data analyst       |    78 | Oxford University         |
| webster  |           23000 | data analyst       |    78 | Oxford University         |
| molina   |           21000 | receptionist       |    81 | UNAM                      |
| jones    |           22000 | law assistant      |    69 | University of Queensland  |
| jones    |           39000 | junior lawyer      |    69 | University of Queensland  |
| lovely   |           26000 | junior analyst     |    71 | Univesity of Bristol      |
| clark    |           23000 | junior banker      |    68 | Harvard Univeristy        |
| clark    |           65000 | head banker        |    68 | Harvard Univeristy        |
| roberts  |           26000 | researcher         |    69 | MIT                       |
| roberts  |           32000 | teacher            |    69 | MIT                       |
| knght    |           28000 | head of department |    92 | University of Barcelona   |
| knght    |           39000 | campus director    |    92 | University of Barcelona   |
| yanagowa |           39000 | database manager   |    86 | Oxford Brookes Univeristy |
| yanagowa |           55000 | head of data       |    86 | Oxford Brookes Univeristy |
+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------+---------------------------+
```

My question is how do I make it only show the highest salary per surname. e.g

yanagowa 55000 head of data 86 Oxford Brookes University
not Yanagowa 39000 database maanger 86 oxford brookes univeristy

please could someone point me in the right direct!

Comment: First you must select and order your data then you must select this ordered data one more time and group by surname. So you must make two selects in one query

Comment: it should be something like - `GROUP BY surname, ORDER BY salary_per_year DESC`.

Comment: This problem has it's own chapter in the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html (but it no longer covers the max-oncat trick - but you'll find explanations of that via Google)

Comment: The uncorrelated subquery solution provided in the manual will in all likelihood prove as fast or faster than any other method you care to try, so I'd stick with that.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me people. the issue is I wanted the highest value. e.g. 55000 not 39000 for yanagowa. I went to group by first. i want the lower amounts to not visable.

Comment: please show expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
SELECT surname, max(salary_per_year) as maxSalary, position_held, grade, name 
FROM person
INNER JOIN career_history on person.person_id = career_history.person_id
JOIN grade on grade.person_id = career_history.person_id
JOIN school on grade.school_id = school.school_id
WHERE salary_per_year > 20000 and grade > 65
GROUP BY surname
ORDER BY Max(salary_per_year) DESC;
```

EDIT

The `ORDER BY` can be shortened actually, this was pointed out after i posted it.

```
ORDER BY maxSalary DESC;
```

Comment: amazing thank you. I was on the right track just needed that push.

Comment: You could simplify the `ORDER BY` clause to `ORDER BY maxSalaray DESC`.

Comment: minus the extra a you put in salary?

Comment: This is true, its a old habit of mine. Marcus is correct tho the syntax could be simplified by using the named column instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Using group by

Note: all fields selected must have a group function(e.g. max, min, sum, avg) if your'e groupping them

```
Select surname, max(salary_per_year) from @yourtable
group by surname
```

Comment: This assumes that none of the other data changes.

Comment: [Mixing aggregate and non-aggregate functions is allowed now](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html). MySQL 5+ will let you be as arbitrary as you want.